# Создать Widget внутри Panel

Tags: extjs

Есть такой панель

```
Ext.define('TelCatalog.view.SearchTelView', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.searchTelView',
    bodyPadding: 10,
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name: 'search',
            fieldLabel: 'Введите данные для поиска:',
            maxLength: 200
        }
    ]
});
```

Как внутри него создать `Grid widget` таким образом что бы он встал в нижний угол ?

Это код панели

```
{
            xtype: 'searchTelView',
            title: '<h4 style="color: Black">Поиск</h4>',
            region: 'west',
            width: 300,
            height: 150,
            collapsible: true,
            collapsed: false
        },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    Ext.define('TelCatalog.view.SearchTelView', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.searchTelView',
    bodyPadding: 10,
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name: 'search',
            region:'center'
            fieldLabel: 'Введите данные для поиска:',
            maxLength: 200
        },
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            region:'south'

        }
    ]
});
```